# Error when closing pipe to sendmail

Tags: linux, perl, sendmail, mojolicious

I am using perl module Mail::Builder::Simple to send email. It using the sendmail utility.
I get this error when sending the email

```
error when closing pipe to sendmail:

Trace begun at /usr/local/share/perl5/Email/Sender/Transport/Sendmail.pm line 79
```

I am sure it's some permission issue, but not sure what exact permission is missing. Any idea what I am missing.

I see this error message in the file located at `/var/spool/clientmqueue/`:

```
550 5.0.0 Access denied
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
```

Comment: [The error message is missing.](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/Email-Sender-1.300006/lib/Email/Sender/Transport/Sendmail.pm#L81) Upgrade Email::Sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this fixed

go to /etc/hosts.allow

add the line

sendmail:ALL at the end of the file and restart sendmail service.